# Не получается отправить POST запрос к url взятому из NSUserDefaults или CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, coredata, xcode7

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

Если я формирую POST-запрос вот так

```
let urlString = url.valueForKey("url") as? String
let myUrl = NSURL(string: urlString!);

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

let postString = "imei=AA022F8E-9E20-482D-80CB-DE06A8CD0990&pin=1234";
request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
```

или вот так

```
requestURL = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(savedPeople) as! String
let myUrl = NSURL(string: requestURL!);

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"      

let postString = "imei=AA022F8E-9E20-482D-80CB-DE06A8CD0990&pin=1234";
request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
```

то, когда посылаю свой запрос, мне приходит ответ, как будто я переслал imei = null и pin = null.

Однако, если я формирую запрос и при этом беру требуемый URL не из CoreData или NSUserDefaults, а просто из переменной типа Sting, вот таким образом

```
let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.wtek.ru/test.php");
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
request.HTTPMethod = "POST";
let postString = "imei=AA022F8E-9E20-482D-80CB-DE06A8CD0990&pin=1234";
request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
```

то все работает корректно.

Сначала я думал, что проблема вот в этом месте находится: `request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)`

и мне нужно поменять кодировку на какую-нибудь другую, но в том случае, если я посылаю запрос внутри себя, на http://127.0.0.1/test.php, а не на внешний адрес,  все работает хорошо.

В чем может быть проблема и есть ли какой-то способ ее решения?

Comment: Так а значения с "CoreData или NSUserDefaults" валидные? Может они не сохраняются туда корректно, от сюда и пустые значения.

Comment: что у вас в urlString и что у вас в requestURL?

Comment: А ты сравнить урлы (которые из разных мест) между собой. Если они не равны, то выведи их в лог. Там явно где-то есть отличия (пробелы, лишние символы и тд).
Также выведи длины урлов.